# Comparing Two Lists in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two sets of files.

Example 1: The filenames are numbered, however, some files may be missing.

Example 1:

Set A:  1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   5.txt   6.txt   7.txt   8.txt

Set B:  1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt   6.txt   7.txt   8.txt

Note: 4.txt is missing from Set A.

I want to compare the two lists.

If I find a match (i.e. 1.txt equals 1.txt), I want to use those two files, together.

When the filenames don't match (i.e. 5.txt and 4.txt), I only want to use 4.txt from Set B.

Continuing on, I want to match the next set (i.e. 5.txt and 5.txt, 6.txt and 6.txt, etc.).

Example 2: There may also be instances where the file lists are as follows:

Example 2:

Set A:  1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt   6.txt   7.txt

Set B:  1.txt   2.txt   4.txt   6.txt   8.txt

Note: 3.txt and 5.txt are missing from Set B.

If I find a match (i.e. 1.txt equals 1.txt, 2.txt equals 2.txt), I want to use those two files, together.

If the filenames don't match (i.e. 3.txt and 4.txt), I only want to use 3.txt from Set A.

Continuing on, I want to match the next set (i.e. 4.txt and 4.txt).

When the filenames don't match (i.e. 5.txt and 6.txt), I only want to use 5.txt from Set A.

Continuing on, I want to match the next set (i.e. 6.txt and 6.txt, etc.) and so on and so on.

So hypothetically, the results (for Example 2) should look as follows:

Set A:  1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt   6.txt   7.txt   N/A

Set B:  1.txt   2.txt   N/A     4.txt   N/A     6.txt   N/A     8.txt

Example 3: There may also be instances where both lists have missing files as follows:

Example 3:

Set A:  2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt   7.txt

Set B:  1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   6.txt   8.txt

Note: 1.txt, 6.txt and 8.txt are missing from Set A -AND- 4.txt, 5.txt and 7.txt are missing from Set B.

I have loaded the 2 lists into 2 separate arrays to do a comparison with no luck.

I have also merged the 2 arrays into 1 array but I have been unable to produce the results that I'm after.

So, without writing an inordinate amount of code (i.e. numerous "if" statements), I was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve this in Perl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*If I find a match, I want to use those two files together*" : What do you mean by "use together"? What is the expected output?

Comment: Basically, I want to read the contents of both files and write the contents of each to another file. If I only find one file, then I want to write the contents of the one file, plus "N/A" in the place of the absent file to another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could iterate through the two sets (if I understand the question correctly):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(uniq);

my @setA = qw(1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt);
my @setB = qw(1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt);

my @all_keys = sort {$a cmp $b} uniq @setA, @setB;
my %setA = map {$_ => 1} @setA;
my %setB = map {$_ => 1} @setB;

for my $key (@all_keys) {
    if (exists $setA{$key} && exists $setB{$key}) {
        # use both $setA{$key} and $setB{$key}
    }
    elsif (exists $setA{$key}) {

    }
    elsif (exists $setB{$key}) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I do believe that I can work with this! ;-) Thank you very much, Håkon. This is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer is very succinct.  I'll just point out that https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare can also helpful for these sorts of problems.